# Here maps javascript events pointerenter and pointerleave do not work for groups

Tags: javascript, here-api, heremaps

I am using [Here maps for javascript v3.1.24.0](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.24.0/api_reference/index.html) within a React application.

My use case is to add an event listener for the '[pointerenter](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.24.0/api_reference/content/H.mapevents.MapEvents.html#event:pointerenter)' and '[pinterleave](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.24.0/api_reference/H.mapevents.MapEvents.html#event:pointerleave)' events to a [group](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.24.0/api_reference/H.map.Group.html).

However, that does not seem to work, while other events like '[tap](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.24.0/api_reference/H.mapevents.MapEvents.html#event:tap)' and '[pointermove](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.24.0/api_reference/H.mapevents.MapEvents.html#event:pointermove)' do work. How can I solve this?

```
const polyLineGroup = new H.map.Group()

polyLineGroup.addObject(polyline);

polyLineGroup.addEventListener("pointerenter", (e) => {
  console.log("pointerenter"); // doesn't work
});

polyLineGroup.addEventListener("pointerleave", (e) => {
  console.log("pointerleave"); //doesn't work
});

polyLineGroup.addEventListener("tap", (e) => {
  console.log("tap"); // works
});

map.addObject(polyLineGroup);
```

Complete example in JS Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/sharmakushagra/nabsxez9/15/

Answer (score 0):

I know, that this question is from year ago, but after two days I found solution, so I leave it for people with the same problem:

In this case addEventListener require third parameter (opt_capture) set on "true".Thanks to this group scope listen to the event listener.

```
    routeLine.addEventListener('pointerenter', function(evt) {
        console.log('test 123', evt) 
    }, true) //<- this true is a key
```